# Review audits in post timeline

Tags: support, review-audits, timeline

I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69437526/timeline) that is being used as a review audit.

In the question's timeline audits completed by users are being shown. Is this a bug or intentional?

It seems to pollute the timeline with irrelevant info to the post itself. What will happen when the post stops being an audit? Do those events get removed? If not, what's the point in keeping them?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The point in keeping them is to see how often posts are being picked out as review audits and whether or not people are passing or failing the audits.

Let's say someone complains that the audit is unfair. We can point to all the people who passed the audit, or we can point to all the other people who failed it to have some evidence as to whether it's fair or not.

If a post is being chosen excessively as an audit we can also see that and when and whether any change to the voting or state of the post stops it being an audit so we can check that the audit choosing rules we expect are being enforced.

Comment: How a post can be excessively used as an audit ? Such as it's only visible by one person it doesn't change anything

Comment: If it was used as an audit 20x as much as any other viable audit post, that would be excessive, no? Or if it was the only post ever chosen as an audit that would be bad too wouldn't it?

Comment: Such as there is lot of people in review, and if it's one of the best choice, I don't know why this should be too many. It can be too many if it was a review but such as it's audit, that doesn't change anything

Comment: If every audit was the same audit post that doesn't really seem right. You'd just go, ahh, that's the audit post I've seen it 20 times before, skip. We want to ensure at least a small amount of thought is required.

Comment: @Elikill58 because the review audits [are picked automatically by the system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/disputed-review-audits/info) and it's a fairly common occurrence that [review audits are disputed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits). Because they can and do cause review suspensions which is problematic in case of a bad audit.